# Does Nim have output buffering?

Tags: echo, flush, nim-lang

Do I have to flush output when I'm using Nim's `echo` like I do with Python's `print`? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flush stdout in Nim with `flushFile(stdout)`: https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#flushFile,File_2

But you don't have to do that since `echo` is equivalent to `writeLine(stdout, x); flushFile(stdout)`: https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#echo,varargs[typed,]